# Image file with iText and Grails

Tags: css, image, grails, pdf-generation, itext

Our project is using iText to generate PDF in a Grails project.

We have a css rule as follows:

```
    .certain-css-class {
        background: transparent url('web-app/images/shapes/xyz.png') 0 50% repeat-x;
    }
```

The problem is that this png image file appears correctly in the PDF when generated in a development environment using "grails run-app" but does not work (does not appear in the PDF) when generated in a production environment using a generated war file.

So far have tried removing the following, none of which work:

```
        background: transparent url('/web-app/images/shapes/xyz.png') 0 50% repeat-x;
        background: transparent url('images/shapes/xyz.png') 0 50% repeat-x;
        background: transparent url('/images/shapes/xyz.png') 0 50% repeat-x;
```

What URL path should we be using that will work in the PDF both from the war and development environments?

Comment: What version of Grails are you using? Are you using the asset pipeline plugin?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore: We are using Grails 2.2.1.  We are not using the asset pipeline plugin.

Comment: I would recommend looking at using the asset pipeline plugin for CSS resources since it will re-write the path for dev vs prod for you.

Comment: If you are using Pdf Plugin, CSS still needs absolute URLs for images, but gsp can have relative.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore: But I am not even sure what the prod path should be?